# How can I get a response from an Apache camel jetty request?

Tags: apache-camel, maven-jetty-plugin, spring-dsl

I am new to apache camel. 
I want to create a service bus (middle ware) using apache camel by making a jetty Post request and then get the response from the server.

Here is what I've done

```
<route streamCache="true">
  <from uri="jetty:{{wrapperEntry.protocol}}://{{wrapperEntry.host}}:{{wrapperEntry.port}}/rsb/SubmitNewCaseForAndroid?continuationTimeout=0" />
  <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
   <to uri="direct:helloworld"/>
</route>

<route streamCache="true">
    <from uri="direct:helloworld"/>
 <transform>
    <simple>
    Hello World
    </simple>
  </transform>

    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
</route>
```

the request goes successfully to the server and submit my case, other wise I cannot get the response back from the server.

Note: the response comes from the is the server is string it comes like this 
'code':0,
'description':'operation completed succrssfully',
'complaintId':'45285'

Thank in Advacnce

Comment: Do you want your route to send the POST (`<to uri=.../>`) or do you want to start a route with a jetty server receiving a POST (`<from uri=.../>`)?

Comment: I'm with Ralf here. I think the question you have and the code you posted are paradoxical. Maybe it would be helpful if you explain more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ralf 
Sorry for the misunderstanding.
I send a request with this URL and I got "Hello World" in the response body. I want to get the response stated upward that comes back from the server.

the request type is POST.

Comment: Your sample route is `<from uri="jetty.../>`. This way you can receive a POST. Not send one.

Comment: @Ralf
 
so how can I send a post and then get back the response ?

Comment: You have to trigger the route by some means (timer, etc.)  and then use  `<to uri="jetty.../>` to send a request to a remote server. The route step after the `<to ../>` will then contain the response from the server in the exchange in-message body.

Comment: @Ralf
Thank you so much.

is there a tutorial or an example so I can walkthrough it?

Comment: @Ralf

is this assupmtion is right ?
<from uri=" {my request}"/> 
<to uri="jetty:{the service URL}"/>
<to uri= "{response}">

Comment: Here's a link to [an article](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html) explaining message exchange patterns in Camel, it should help.

Comment: @Ralf can you help me on this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831460/jms-from-synchronous-to-asynchronous

Comment: @Cyäegha
can you help me on this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831460/jms-from-synchronous-to-asynchronous