# JMS from Synchronous to Asynchronous

Tags: spring, asynchronous, apache-camel, jms

I was able to create a Synchronous service bus using the JMS, but I was not able to turn it to Asynchronous.
I'm trying to post a request to a service asynchronously, so if the service is down, I want the JMS queue keeps the request message and when the service starts up it delivers the message to the service and get back the response.

here is my code

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route >
            <from id ="server" uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9500/rsb/toService?matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;enableMultipartFilter=false&amp;disableStreamCache=false"/>
            <wireTap uri="log:test?level=INFO"><body><simple>Enter JMS test route and sending message to queue</simple></body></wireTap>
            <!--<to uri="direct:queue"/>-->
            <to uri="jms://testqueue?requestTimeout=360000&amp;replyTo=bar&amp;replyToDeliveryPersistent=true&amp;exchangePattern=InOut&amp;acknowledgementModeName=AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
        </route>
        <route id="testqueuelistener" streamCache="true">
            <from uri="jms://testqueue?replyToDeliveryPersistent=true&amp;replyTo=bar" />
            <wireTap uri="log:test?level=INFO"><body><simple>Message recieved from queue: ${body}</simple></body></wireTap>             
            <to uri="http://localhost:18402/Home/addUser?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
            <to uri="jms:service"/> 
        </route>
        <route >
            <from uri="jms:service"/>
            <transform>
                <simple>${body}</simple>
            </transform>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Comment: What is the actual issue you meet (what happens when you try this)? Also, which JMS implementation do you use, and how is it configured?

Comment: jms configuration <osgi:reference id="jmsConnectionPool" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/> <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent"> <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionPool" /> </bean> 


my actual issue is if the service "localhost:18402/Home/addUser"; is down -not running- I got Error 404 Not Found 
Problem accessing /rsb/toService. Reason:  Not Found

I was hoping to keep the request message in the queue "testqueue" until the service starts up and then receive the message in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are accessing the JMS queue without using a transaction - so as soon as you get the message, it's gone from the queue. You need to use a transaction and only commit (or rollback) the message consumption after you've finished processing it.

The relevant Enterprise Integration Pattern is the [transactional client](http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html). The [JMS component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) also provides some information about transaction. Finally, chapter 9 of Camel in Action (chapter 12 for the second edition) is dedicated to transactions (and I can't recommend it enough!).

You need to:

- Obtain a JMS transaction manager (which transaction manager you use may depend on your specific use case)
- Configure the Camel JMS component to use the transaction manager
- Use a transaction policy to configure the transactional behavior of your route (or just mark the route as transacted, and use the default policy)

The configuration can look something like:

```
<!-- Import JMS connection factory -->
<osgi:reference id="jmsConnectionPool" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
<!-- We create a Spring JmsTransactionManager (our transaction manager could also be an
imported OSGi service, like we do for the connection factory; for example an XA transaction
manager) -->
<bean id="jmsTxManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionPool"/>
</bean>
<!-- We configure the JMS component to use the transaction manager-->
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionPool" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTxManager"/>
</bean>

<!-- Here's an example of a transaction policy -->
<bean id="requiresNew" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW"/>
</bean>
```

Here's a transacted route:

```
<route id="myRoute">
    <from uri="jms://..." />
    <transacted/>
    ...
</route>
```

And a route can use a specific transaction policy if we want:

```
<route id="myRoute">
    <from uri="jms://..." />
    <transacted ref="requiresNew" />
    ...
</route>
```

Comment: can I add the same option while I am getting the response?